# How to restyle tooltip color context label for series?

Tags: highcharts

I'm overriding the tooltip to convert from epoch time and with that I lose my color context coding for my series.  it defaults to black.  By default high charts adds color context with the name of the series in the tooltip.

How can I restyle so that the series name is the same color as series line?

Fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/EwpWh/3/

```
 tooltip: {
     enabled: true,
     formatter: function() {
               return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + 
               '<br/>'+ this.series.name +': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,0) + '</b>';
                 }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following will work:

```
  formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +
            '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + ' ">'+ this.series.name +'</span>: <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,0) + '</b>';
              }
```

},